# Fluid full window width carousel using jQuery.carouFredSel

Tags: javascript, html, caroufredsel

I am trying to use the following gallery/carousel http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/ to implement onto a site.

What I am trying to do is add a text area identifying who created the image next to it, i.e. having the image in a div floated to the left and the content floated to the right.

I create the div and set it all out in css and looks all ok but for some reason the carousel does not work, its like there is a problem with adding HTML tags.

Has anyone used this carousel and had a div rotating with an image and text in it if so please help me.

Cheers Andy.